# Android: getContext() in Fragment returns null only when leaving over the Back Button

Tags: android, android-context

i have a Fragment, which contains and ArrayList of Pending Notification Intents.

I build that list of reminders in onPause(), because i only want the to show up when the App is not running in the foreground.

Everything works fine if i leave the app over the HomeScreen Button, but if i leave over the Back Button, the Compiler tells me i try to call getSystemService() on a Null Reference.

Main Activitie's onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    tasksFragment.buildReminderList();
}
```

Here the method from the Fragment:

```
public void buildReminderList() {

    mReminderList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (mTaskList != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < mTaskList.size(); i++) {

            if (mTaskList.get(i).hasReminder() && mTaskList.get(i).getMillisLeftToday() > 0) {

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                intent = new Intent(getContext(), AlertReceiver.class);

                intent.putExtra("title", mTaskList.get(i).getName());
                intent.putExtra("ID", i);

                alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), i, intent, 0);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mTaskList.get(i).getReminderHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mTaskList.get(i).getReminderMinutes());

                if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, alarmIntent);

                mReminderList.add(alarmIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pressing the back button, the fragment is no longer attached to the activity, so `getContext()` returns null.

You can check if your fragment is still added to the activity and then call your `getSystemService`like below

```
if (isAdded()) {
   getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that avoids the crashing. But then it doesnt save the Reminder List anymore. Any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: You have to use a service to achieve that, read about [broadcast receivers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Thank you. I guess i can also just move the whole buildReminderList method out of the fragment into the main activity.

Comment: It worked after i put the method into the MainActivity. But i also use the TaskFragment reference to pull the TaskList out of it. So i assume the Fragment reference is still working, but i just cant get the Context, because it is not attached anymore?